# Rate your GM: Evaluation Method & Questionnaire for Players

Tags: gm-techniques

I've concluded this year's campaign, and I would like to collect feedback from my players (5 constant plus 5 more on/off) about my performance as a GM.

I didn't find any relevant QAs in RPG.SE

Online I only found a [post in Giant in the Playground](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?386870-Rate-your-DM!), which apparently offers three dimensions of rating:

- **Story** - Do they create an interesting plot, and continue to reference interactions with NPCs?
- **Mechanics** - Do they understand the rules, and if they homebrew rules, do they do it well?
- **Adaptability** - Do they respond well to you changing the plot by out-of-the-box thinking, and changing the pace of the campaign?

The only other online resource I found was a [post in Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/3coxhl/what_kind_of_dungeon_master_are_you/) (***for self-evaluation***) which went along the lines of:

- **Style**: e.g. *I am not a "rules guy" - I try to run my games as if they are a weekly TV show and my players are the stars*.
- **Campaign**: e.g. *I use published adventures, but I have placed all of my games in the same homebrewed setting for many years of real life time*.
- **Issues**: e.g. *The thing I find hardest is finding that sweet spot where everything clicks - often times my games are too easy or the story isn't quite grabbing them right*.
- **Player Problem**: e.g. *I can't stand players who can't handle adversity. I've had grown men throw temper tantrums over a difficult encounter ("Who designed this?!" is their battle cry)*.

I would like to know if there is some more-to-the-point (and maybe more official or standardized) way to collect player feedback about their GM.

**Fellow GMS**: Which are the qualities of a GM's performance and how can we quantify them to capture Players' feedback?

I'm not sure there exists a correct answer to the question, but I still think it is an interesting one. Criteria for the best answer will be: most complete and justified with online authoritative material.

Comment: We don't handle opinion polls here. See our [questions to avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). We focus on solving practical problems, not discussions and opinion collection. Perhaps [ask this on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)?